# exception while importing module in ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, plugins, npm, require

I need to remove diacritics from string in emberjs app.
I found a plugin for this: [fold-to-ascii](https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii)
but I don't know how to use it in my app.

I added this plugin via npm and it is visible under node_modules folder in my app

In docs usage of this plugin is:

```
var foldToAscii = require("fold-to-ascii");
foldToAscii.fold("★Lorém ïpsum dölor.")
```

but i get an exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module fold-to-ascii
```

also tried importing it like @Kori John Roys suggested:

```
import foldToAscii from 'fold-to-ascii'
```

but it gives me only new exception:

`Error while processing route: transports.index 
Could not find module fold-to-ascii imported from test-ember/pods/transport/model`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using ember-cli:

```
npm install --save-dev ember-browserify
```

then you can import like this:

```
import foldToAscii from "npm:fold-to-ascii"
```

Comment: tried it and now I get error: Error while processing route: transports.index Could not find module `fold-to-ascii` imported from `test-ember/pods/transport/model` Error: Could not find module `fold-to-ascii` imported from `test-ember/pods/transport/model`, should I point import to node_modules folder ?

Comment: ah yes, you're right sorry. You'll want to `npm install --save-dev ember-browserify`, then `import foldToAscii from "npm:fold-to-ascii"`