# import node js module in ember js framework

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to import a simple node js module into Ember js. I followed the quick start at https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.8.0/getting-started/quick-start/ and got the People List working.

Then I added the simple upper-case module using `npm install upper-case` and added `app.import('node_modules/upper-case/upper-case.js');` to `ember-cli-build.js` as mentioned in https://guides.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/.

After that, I opened `scientists.js` and added import to `upper-case` as follows:

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
//import uc from 'upper-case';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    var arr = new Array();
    arr[0] = 'Marie Curie'; // uc('Marie Curie');
    arr[1] = 'Mae Jemison';
    arr[2] = 'Albert Hofmann';
    return arr;
  }
});
```

If I remove the comments, it shows me a blank screen. If I use `'Marie Curie'.toUpperCase()` it works, but I want to be able to import such node modules.  How can I achieve this?

I have already tried [exception while importing module in ember js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672404/exception-while-importing-module-in-ember-js) and `ember-auto-import`, but they don't seem to work for me.  The above method I tried seems to be simple and would be nice if it can work this way.

PS: I could make `upper-case` work in other JS frameworks such as React and Vue, so the module itself doesn't have any issues.

Comment: What version of ember are you using?

Comment: ember-cli: 3.8.1

Comment: do you have ember-browserify installed? I saw that was mentioned in your link before ember-auto-import. Uninstall ember-browserify if you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you install ember-auto-import, you'll be able to use any npm package like how the particular npm package's documentation says to use it (provided the particular npm package is configured correctly on build).

https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import

This'll be a default soon (and is recommended over using app.import)

The reason ember-auto-import is recommended over app.import is because there are ~ 5 different module formats JS can exist in, and you *need* to worry about those when using app.import. ember-auto-import, powered by webpack, abstracts all that away from you.

fwiw, JS has `.toUpperCase()` built in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

so you don't need *that* particular module.

#### Edit

> I have already tried exception while importing module in ember js and ember-auto-import, but they don't seem to work for me. The above method I tried seems to be simple and would be nice if it can work this way.

did you get any errors with this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info.  I tried browserify and it gave some error.. I am trying it again and letting you know what error..

Comment: cool! fwiw, browserify is not recommended anymore. It blows up bundle size significantly.

Comment: About `ember-auto-import`, it appears i have to include my import under webpack, if I understood the doc correctly.. I will be deploying using some other server, so I am not sure how to configure that..

Comment: ember-auto-import *should* be 0 config. So you shouldn't have to worry about anything. (most of the time you don't even have to read the docs)

Comment: `// In your addon's index.js file
module.exports = {
  name: 'sample-addon',
  options: {
    autoImport:{
      exclude: ['some-package'],
      webpack: {
        // extra webpack configuration goes here
      }
    }
  }
};`

Comment: and deploying is totally unrelated to ember-auto-import, so when you're ready to deploy, feel free to open another stack overflow question if ya get stuck :+1:

Comment: You were right.. `ember-auto-import` worked.. thanks.

Comment: woo! glad you got it working! Sorry for the confusion. Docs are getting updated soon!